# How to load/import a PNG image as plane via Blender's Python API?

Tags: python, image

I have the following snippet to load an image as plane; however, this seems to be obsolete in newer versions of Blender such as 2.79.

```
bpy.ops.import_image.to_plane(use_shadeless=True, files=[{'name':file_path}])
```

I need to import a local PNG image as plane that will always face camera. What is the new API to do so in version 2.79?

The error I'm receiving in the console is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\~~~~\Text", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.import_image.to_plane" error, could not be found
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

Answer (score 5):

The `use_shadeless` has been replaced with `shader` which accepts values of `DIFFUSE`, `SHADELESS` or `EMISSION`.

```
bpy.ops.import_image.to_plane(shader='SHADELESS', files=[{'name':file_path}])
```

For other options, if you manually do an import image as planes and have [python tooltips](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/interface.html) enabled you can find the property name in the tooltips

[image: propertry tooltips]

Comment: Why are you not using the Import Images as Planes addon itself? The operator is missing otherwise because that ops.import_image.to_plane is not native to Blender....

Comment: Thanks @CraigDJones and sambler. combining both of your answers resolved my case. added community wiki answer

Answer (score 2):

## Misconfigured Blender Environment

In addition to [@sambler](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122020/27191)'s answer, You'll need to set the following settings  to get the snippet work properly.

```
bpy.ops.import_image.to_plane(shader='SHADELESS', files=[{'name':file_path}])
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you are trying to automate the task using python, you can also enable an addon using python.

```
bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module='io_import_images_as_planes')
```

And you can install new addons if needed.

```
bpy.ops.wm.addon_install(filepath='/path/to/newaddon.py')
```