# Shaders Nodes - Attaching and detaching nodes with python

Tags: python, materials, scripting, node-editor, shaders

I would like to import an image as a plane, then add a *MixShader* and a *Transparent BSDF*, detach the *Material Output Surface* link, attach the *BSDF* to the *MixShader*, to the *Material Output*, then add the *Transparent BSDF* to the *Mix Shader*.

Is this possible to do with python coding? I am totally lost. My goal is making the image imported transparent with a script for *EEVEE*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The linked dupe should pretty much answer your question. Otherwise please post your code so we can help out with details...

Comment: Note: You can also pass `use_transparency=True` when calling the image as planes operator: `bpy.ops.import_image.to_plane(use_transparency=True, files=[{'name':your_filepath}])`, related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121980/

Comment: ...also .  numerous other python related node questions. Eg https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145882/blender-scripting-connect-nodes   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/how-to-connect-nodes-to-node-group-inputs-and-outputs-in-python  @susu come on mate,  is that (_easily interpreted as passive aggresive_) comment ever the least part helpful to the OP?  For example Why  here but not [here?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208683/how-to-make-a-realistic-pepsi-material)